# Angular - Validator in an input file field

Tags: angular, typescript

In angular, how can I make a obrigatory field validator for a field that will be inserted a file in? Validator.required is not working in this case.

Html:

```
<input class="input" type="text" formControlName="document" value="{{arquivosSelecionados[0] ? arquivosSelecionados[0][0].name : ''}}" disabled>
                
<app-form-messages class="md-inputfield"  [field]="formIncluirMembros.get('document')"></app-form-messages>
```

Typescript

```
this.formIncluirMembros.addControl("document", new FormControl(null, Validators.required));
```

Comment: a FormControl "disabled" NOT validate, you can use `[attr.disabled]="true"`  (or `[attr.disabled]="variable"` -this don't disable the FormControl else the input-

Answer (score 0):

Remove `disabled` in input rather use `readonly` if suit your requirement. As adding it will exempt from validation checks as per [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled).